# For Method of Undetermined Coefficients, what is the guess for a constant to the power of x? Eg. 2+2^x

Tags: initial-value-problems

I'm doing a initial value problem and need to use the method of undetermined coefficients. I have on the right side 2+2^x, and I'm unsure what guess I would use for this. I've seen every possible circumstance except for this case. For example, for e^3x, I would use Ae^3x. But what about 2+2^x?

Comment: Remember $a^x=e^{\ln(a) x}$ so it is really the same case as $e^{cx}$.

Comment: the ODE is 2u_(k+1) - 7u_k + 3u_(k-1) = 2 + 2^k

Comment: So we're not actually talking about an ODE ("Ordinary Differential Equation"), we're talking about a recurrence relation. Note that $2^x=e^{x\log2}$.

Comment: Did that help? Do you see how to do it now?

Comment: Are you still here?